# Several users requesting 30,000 rows of information simultaneously

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a test bed application available to 3 users.

If all users run the app at the same time, then a stored procedure runs, and all three will have result sets, currently using `ADO.NET Datatable` of approx 30,000 records which the app then needs to move into an Excel template for each of them.

The template is an `xlsm` file which contains some `VBA` that needs to run after importing the data. This template is saved in the solution.

I'm going to attempt to move the data from the`DataTable` to a `worksheet` using `Excel-Interop`

Has anyone any experience of moving this amount of data from Datatable into Excel?

@slugster suggested "setting up a datasource from Excel and just run the query using a dirty read" ... is it possible to set up a datasource in `Excel` linked to a non-materialized datatable?

Will looping through a table that is 30000 rows by 10 columns via `xl interop` run into problems?

Comment: What is the problem here? Did you *try* to do it and it went wrong?  Were the results invalid? Was it too slow? Did you profile your code?

Comment: Agree with Dariusz - Make it work then make it fast and profile, profile profile!  I'd let SQL server worry about caching the data  initially, that's what it's good at.  You are far more likely to have problems loading and manipulating that amount of data in Excel.

Comment: Yes you will get locking and index fragmentation issues if you use a holding table. Why not set up a datasource from Excel and just run the query using a dirty read?

Comment: @slugster - are you able to expand this comment?

Comment: @DariuszWawer Nothing written or failing yet; as this is new to me I thought I'd try to get some advice on the best way forward - sounds like I can just let the stored proc return the data and read it from cache - don't worry about a holding table

Comment: 30,000 rows shouldn't be that much (assuming it's not 100 columns wide). Add a few zeros on that and you may run into issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Has anyone any experience of moving this amount of data from Datatable
>   into Excel?

Not from a DataTable object, but that amount of data using Excel's built in ability to import data, yes.

> @slugster suggested "setting up a datasource from Excel and just run
>   the query using a dirty read" ... is it possible to set up a
>   datasource in Excel linked to a non-materialized datatable?

I would suggest this as well. To go further, I'd suggest creating a stored procedure then calling that. You should see better performance using a stored procedure. The procedure could collect and prepare the data then return it to Excel. Also, you may be able to build in a caching mechanism inside the procedure. For example, if your data only changes daily, you only rebuild the data in the source table once per day, so only the first user to request the data takes an initial performance hit. Also, depending on what type of post processing you are doing in Excel in VBA, maybe that could be handled in the procedure as well. The procedure will also help reduce the possibility of locking issues if you add SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED to the top of the procedure, or use the (NOLOCK) hint on the tables you are willing to allow dirty reads from.

Here's a nice article regarding using stored procedures in Excel: http://codebyjoshua.blogspot.com/2012/01/get-data-from-sql-server-stored.html

> Will looping through a table that is 30000 rows by 10 columns via xl
>   interop run into problems?

This depends on your definition of "problems." I could see possible performance implications, however if you handle as much as you can in the stored procedure, you should be fine. In the world of data, that's really teeny tiny.